# If block does not get executed on truthy condition. JS

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I stumbled upon unexpected behaviour in JS. If I log `regexpr.test(inp)` , console outputs `true`, yet if this code is used as condition 'if block' `console.log('in if');` is not executed.

If I assign this code to a variable and then use it as a condition 'if block' gets executed as expected.

Tested it in chrome console and node.

```
var str = '()'

function validateInput (inp) {

  let regexpr = /^(?:\(|\)|\s)+$/gim
  console.log(regexpr.test(inp));   // logs true
  if (regexpr.test(inp)) {          // staments in if are not executed
    console.log('in if');
  }
  console.log('after if');
  return false
}

function validateInput2 (inp) {

  let regexpr = /^(?:\(|\)|\s)+$/gim
  let t1 = regexpr.test(inp);
  console.log(t1);                  // logs true
  if (t1) {                         // staments in if are executed
    console.log('in if');
  }
  console.log('after if');
  return false
}

console.log(validateInput(str));
console.log('------')
console.log(validateInput2(str));
```

```
true
after if
false
------
true
in if
after if
false
```

Comment: Don't use the global flag unless you actually need the global flag

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're matching the string from start to end - you don't need to use the `g` (global) flag at all.

```
let regexpr = /^(?:\(|\)|\s)+$/im;
```